# Bouncing Particles in a CCParticleSystemQuad

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone, particles

I'm using cocos2d to make a game on iOS. I have a particle emitter that I want the particles to bounce when they hit the bottom of the screen. Thing is I cannot seem to find a way to do this and with my limited understand of open GL the answer my be obviously in front of me but I don't see it. Is there an example of this or a way to use the CCBounce or box2d or something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bouncing ball tutorial which uses cocos2d + Box2D:

- http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls

There is also EaseBounce actions (`CCEaseBounceIn`, `CCEaseBounceOut`, `CCEaseBounceInOut`) in cocos2d for you to run on sprites. See "EaseBounce actions" section in ["cocos2d Programming Guide: Actions - Ease"](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide%3aactions_ease).